# Arrange nodes with python

Tags: python, node-editor, add-on

I am trying to get my dynamically created material nodes aligned per script.
Since the "Node Arrange"- Addon does a good job at aligning nodes I would like to use that. I have managed to get it activated with

```
addon_utils.enable("node_arrange")
```

But I don't know how to go from there. I just want to execute the "Arrange all nodes"-button from the addon, but I don't know how to do it without getting any errors.

When executing bpy.ops.node.button() I get an error:

> 'SpaceView3D' object has no attribute 'node_tree'

Any advice?

Comment: https://github.com/JuhaW/NodeArrange/issues/10

Comment: Hey JuhaW. That unfortunately doesn't do anything for me.